# How to appended to a text file in python to record new record without removing it

Tags: python, ms-access, append

How do you append to the file instead of overwriting it? Is there a special function that appends to the file?

Comment: you forgot to tell us what your existing problem and/or error is. But I'm going to guess it's because you send a static SQL string to the database, not one in which you set parameters. I think you need @ in front of the parameter names in the VALUES section of the query. Also you seem not to have created parameters for all of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get rid of the extra parenthesis

   `Public myadonetconnection2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection((connectionstring))`
2. You never use dataadapter2, commandbuilder2 or datatable2 - delete
3. You can't pass a DataAdapter as a parameter to a command constructor. Pass the query string and a connection object.
4. You have created your cmd object twice
5. Add the rest of your cmd.Parameters ; you stopped at answerA. Your names are fine, just make sure the column names are correct and in the same order as your database columns.
6. You cannot open a string. You need to Open your connection object
7. I don't see a cmdOLEDB defined anywhere. You want to execute your cmd object.
8. You can't Close a string. You want to close your connection object.
   There is more... like disposing of objects with using statements but we have covered a great deal and that is for another day.

   ```
   Private Sub InsertQuestion()
               Dim strConnectionString = " Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12;Data Source=" & System.Environment.CurrentDirectory & "mathsquiz.accdb"
   Dim description, realanswer, answera, answerb, answerc, answerd As String
           description = txtdescription.Text
           realanswer = txtrealanswer.Text
           answera = txtanswera.Text
           answerb = txtanswerb.Text
           answerc = txtanswerc.Text
           answerd = txtanswerd.Text
           Dim myadonetconnection2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(strConnectionString)
           Dim InsertQuery As String = "INSERT INTO question
           (questiondescription, realanswer, answerA, answerB, answerC,answerD) 
           VALUES (description,realanswer,answera,answerb,answerc,answerd)"
           Dim cmd As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(InsertQuery, myadonetconnection2)
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("description", description)
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("realanswer", realanswer)
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("answera", answera)
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("answerb", answerb)
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("answerc", answerc)
           cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("answerd", answerd)
           myadonetconnection2.Open()
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
           myadonetconnection2.Close()
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: The fields and column names can be used in any order in the command.  Just make sure parameters are listed in the same order as in the command.

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf The database is probably Access (Ace provider) Access does not care what you name your parameters. It only cares about the order in which they are added.

Comment: From MSDN

The OLE DB.NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text.

Therefore, the order in which OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must directly correspond to the position of the placeholder for the parameter in the command text.

If they are not, the data will be saved to the wrong colums

Comment: Database Column names can still be used in any order as long as the parameter has the same position as the placeholder.

Comment: @TheWhiteWolf Got it. Thank you for clearing that up for me.